# How to compare oldMap and newMap in a trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a multipicklist called relatedActivity on an SObject called premises. Every time there is change in the relatedActivity or an option is deleted from the relatedactivity, i want to execute a certain function. I am having trouble getting the change/the deleted option from the pickList. This is what I have done so far:

```
if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate){
    Set<String> premisesIds = new Set<String>();
    String differences;
    for(RS_Premises__c pr : (List<RS_Premises__c>) newlist){
        RS_Premises__c thisPremises = (RS_Premises__c)oldmap.get(pr.Id);
        RS_Premises__c newPremises = (RS_Premises__c)newmap.get(pr.Id);
        String diff1 = String.valueOf(thisPremises.Related_Activity__c);
        String diff2 = String.valueOf(newPremises.related_Activity__c);
        List<String> x = diff1.split(';');
        List<String> y = diff2.split(';');
        differences = y.get(0).difference(x.get(0));
        System.debug('The old Map : ' + x);
        System.debug('The new Map : ' + y);
        System.debug('The difference in related activity change : ' + differences);//split(';', 3)
}
```

Although, I am getting both the old and new values correctly. just wanted to compare the differences and see which options have been deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [Set](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_set.htm) would be useful here. Put all the values that you split out into a Set and then remove those from the other split.

E.g.

[image]

```
// ...
List<String> x = diff1.split(';');
List<String> y = diff2.split(';');
// ...

// Find picklist values that have been removed. A in the diagram
Set<string> aSet = new Set<string>();
aSet.addAll(x);
aSet.removeAll(y);

// Find the picklist values that have been added. B In the diagram
Set<string> bSet = new Set<string>();
bSet.addAll(y);
bSet.removeAll(x);
```